# Error "Unable to find class: TKApplication, exiting" when attempting to use Tkinter inside existing Cocoa application

Tags: python, tkinter

### The requirement

I need to use Tkinter in an instance of Python that is embedded inside an existing Cocoa GUI application.

### What I've tried

On Windows, this was as simple (glossing over a *lot* of details) as building Python as a library, linking against it and the Tcl/Tk libraries downloaded by Python's build process, and then calling Tkinter from Python's C API and from embedded Python code.

Following the same general idea on the Mac, I've built (static) libraries of Python, Tcl, and Tk using the standard Unix `configure`/`make`/`make install` process. This allows me both to use Tkinter in the Python executable built at the same time, and to run Python code inside my app, but when I try to invoke Tkinter in my app (with a call to `tkinter.Tk()` I get an Objective-C exception:

```
[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040001018c0
```

From reading the Tk documentation, it seems that Cocoa Tkinter works by subclassing `NSApplication`, the code for which can be found in [tkMacOSXPrivate.h](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/c7891f2a92433b56):

```
@interface TKApplication : NSApplication {
```

The error therefore occurs because my app isn't using this subclass, so when Tk's `TkpInit` function runs the [following code](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/33a9a7e588f9d5b7) the object returned by `sharedApplication` is an `NSApplication`, not a `TKApplication`:

```
[TKApplication sharedApplication];
[NSApp _setup:interp];
```

According to the [`NSApplication` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication?language=objc), the fix for this is simply to set 'your custom app class to be the principal class' by replacing '"NSApplication" in the Principal Class field with the name of your custom class' (i.e. setting the `NSPrincipalClass` in the app's `Info.plist`.

However, after having done so, I then get the following error at app startup:

```
Unable to find class: TKApplication, exiting
```

It seems that Cocoa cannot find the class that is defined in the tk library that I built.

### Questions:

1. Is this the correct approach for using Tkinter from an instance of Python that is inside an exiting GUI app?
2. Why can't Cocoa find the TKApplication class?